# Java Spring Security 5 + MySQL Database: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm creating a Web Application with Java and Spring. I'm using the Java JDK 12, Sping Boot 2.1.6, Spring Security 5 and Thymeleaf 3.0.11.

I'm using Spring Security for the user authentification. I want to store the user data (username, password, etc.) in a MySQL database.

I already created a user in my database and encrypted the password with BCrypt.

When I try to login using my login form, I get the message "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt".

I think that the problem is, that I have to imlement the BCryptPasswordEncoder.

I already tried all the other posts on Stackoverflow and other websites, but I couldn't understand how to implement the password encoder to work with the MySQL database.

*SpringSecurity.class*

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
                .csrf();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
    }
}
```

Comment: How you encoded your password using BCrypt ?

Comment: This is a common error if the used database truncate the hash inside table or the column's width is less than the required space (in general 60). Make sure that the column's width is at least 60 characters, `password VARCHAR(60)` respectively `@Column(length = 60)`. I would guess this is the reason for this error. Am I right?

Comment: @0x1C1B Unfortunately not. I'm using `VARCHAR(85)`. I did this fault earlier, but I noticed it myself.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati Yes I have encoded it using BCrpyt. For example `123456` -> `$2y$12$rgWnBViVDQ6W7z3bf9IJJOwkN83JYeATlRrKRZsbVUOhmygjWUgHa` .

Comment: @Simon And the java implementation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the password encrypting on your `configAuthentication` method. Take a look at this example:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.jdbcAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()).dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usernameQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(authoritiesQuery);
    }
```

Just add the passwordEncoder configuration referencing the `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, you can also define a custom bean to handle that encryption.